# Как быстро проверить делимость числа?

Tags: c++, перебор

Есть 2 числа, нужно найти за короткое время на КАКИЕ числа они оба делятся без остатка? Как это можно сделать? Если пытаться обычным циклом, то получается слишком медленно. Примеру 12 и 6, они оба делятся без остатка на 1, 2, 3, 6.

Comment: "обычным циклом" - ?

Comment: А зачем одно число делить на другое циклом? Вы что-то не договариваете - вопрос не полный.

Comment: gcd чтоли найти?..

Comment: @nick_n_a Есть 2 числа, надо проверить на КАКИЕ числа они делятся без остатка, например 12 и 6, ответ будет 1,2,3,6

Comment: ну да. ищите gcd потом его все делители чем-то адекватным и всё.

Comment: Есть в математике задача, которая называется нахождение наибольшего или наименьшего общего делителя. НОД. Читаете внимательно алгоритм - и переносите на с++. Да и вообше посмотрите топ 10 гугла на запрос "НОД" - там куча решений.

Comment: так а вам надо простые делители или все? есть алгоритмы факторизации, но они основаны на проверке делимости на простые числа, т.е. 12 будет представлено как 2*2*3, а не 2*6

Comment: @goldstar_labs надо чтобы было представлено 2 числами

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, на отсутствии быстрого алгоритма разложения чисел на простые множители строится всё современное шифрование, в том числе и всякие цифровые подписи и биткоины. То же, в принципе, касается и разложения на множители вообще. Так что, мне кажется, у Кнута эта задача имела бы сложность 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сложность алгоритма O(sqrt(n))

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

typedef long long ll;

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;

    int gcd = __gcd(a, b);

    vector <int> v;

    for(int i=1; i*i <= gcd; i++) {
        if(gcd % i == 0) {
            if(i*i == gcd) 
                { v.push_back(i); }
            else {
                v.push_back(i);
                v.push_back(gcd/i);
            }
        }
    }

    sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for(auto el : v)
        cout << el << " ";

    return 0;
}
```